# SQL query to DQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, dql

I have a big query and I want to add a subquery to get the availability of accommodation-rooms.

This is the SQL subquery:

```
,(SELECT (CASE WHEN count(_days) > 0 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'No' END) as available
FROM
(
  SELECT count(rtd.room_type_id) as _days
    FROM room_type_day as rtd
    WHERE rtd.date IN ('2018-06-20', '2018-06-21', '2018-06-22')
    GROUP BY rtd.room_type_id
    HAVING COUNT(rtd.room_type_id) = 3
) as sub) as availability
```

Can anyone tell me how to convert this SQL in DQL?

Thak you

**EDIT**

I try with this changes but the response is null every time:

```
,(SELECT (CASE WHEN count(rtd.roomType) > 0 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END)
    FROM AppBundle:RoomTypeDayCancelationConditionAccommodation as RTDCCA2
    LEFT JOIN RTDCCA2.roomTypeDay as rtd
    WHERE rtd.date IN ('2018-06-20', '2018-06-21', '2018-06-22')
    GROUP BY rtd.roomType
    HAVING COUNT(rtd.roomType) = 3
) as disponible
```

Comment: [Formulating complicated Doctrine2 DQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518728/formulating-complicated-doctrine2-dql-query/25606307#25606307)

Comment: Hi @MKhalidJunaid the problem was on trying to do the subquery "SELECT count(...". Doctrine return me this error message: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 1198 near '(
SELECT': Error: Class '(' is not defined.